# BiCubic Shaper PHP Image Resize

Tags: php, image-processing, resize, gd, imagemagick

Photoshop has that great:
BiCube Shaper option for resizing.

However I cannot find an equivalent.

I've seen various code using GD that used imagecopyresampled and custom unsharp mask, but no where near the quality I am expecting.

Any help?

Comment: Are you upsizing or downsizing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you've tried is GD, you might want to give some of the ImageMagick sampling filters a shot.  Here's a page that examines them along with the PhotoShop ones:

http://www.xs4all.nl/~bvdwolf/main/foto/down_sample/down_sample.htm